# Removing Nodes from a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mercer/Projects/BSTRemoveGeneric.pdf

**I am having trouble with coding this!
I don't know why this does't work! It drive me crazy!!!!**
Remove method for OrderedSet.
Here is my code

```
public boolean remove(E element)
{
    if(root == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(!contains(element))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(root.data.equals(element) && root.left != null)
    {
        root = root.left;
        return true;
    }
    //return remove(element, root);
    else
    {
        TreeNode curr = root;
        TreeNode prev = root;
        while(element.compareTo(curr.data) != 0 && curr != null)
        {
           prev = curr;
           if(element.compareTo(curr.data) < 0)
           {
                curr = curr.left;
           }
           else// if(element.compareTo(curr.data) > 0)
           {
                curr = curr.right;
           }
        }
        if(curr.left == null)
        {
            if(curr == prev.left)
            {
                prev.left = curr.right;
            }
            else// if(curr == prev.right)
            {
                prev.right = curr.right;
            }
            return true;
        }


        else// if(curr.left != null)
        {
            OrderedSet<E> temp = new OrderedSet<E>();
            temp.root = curr.left;
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n" + curr.data +  "\n" + prev.data +  "\n" + temp.toStringInorder() + "\n" + temp.max() + "\n\n\n\n");
            curr.data = temp.max();
            TreeNode ref = curr;
            while(curr.right != null)
            {
                ref = curr;
                curr = curr.right;
            }
            ref = ref.left;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Errors:

Failed after remove("G") after inserting G A D C

Failed size after call to intersection.

Failed to remove root node when the root node has left child (

failed intersection when both have three of the same elements

failed remove root with more to the right

Failed remove after insert("M"); insert("G"); remove("M");

Are you using '==' instead of 'equals'? Failed remove after insert(new Integer(50)); insert(new Integer(75)); remove(new Integer(50));

Failed size during remove (2 occurrences)

(only 8 of 9 hints shown)

Comment: What's the exact error? It is impossible to help with so little information.

Comment: Failed after remove("G") after inserting G A D C

Failed size after call to intersection.

Failed to remove root node when the root node has left child (

failed intersection when both have three of the same elements

failed remove root with more to the right

Failed remove after insert("M"); insert("G"); remove("M");

Are you using '==' instead of 'equals'? Failed remove after insert(new Integer(50)); insert(new Integer(75)); remove(new Integer(50));

Failed size during remove (2 occurrences)

(only 8 of 9 hints shown)

Comment: I'm sorry but that's still not enough. You are giving us error messages that come from outside the code you are posting. Afaik, the error may not even be in this part of the code you gave.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to have the following

```
f(!contains(element))
{
    return false;
}
```

Consider the case where the element you are removing exists in the tree, this means that you're doing this extra computation.

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/JK6qLBxe) some code I wrote ages ago. Warning: It is extremely long --- most of it is redundant.

Comment: I already have this method. In the whole java file, this is just part of it.